# Custom Cleaner on Django Form - Not working

Tags: python, regex, django, forms

I have a search form where users can, among other options, search by regular expression. I'm trying to add a custom cleaner to catch invalid regular expressions (otherwise it triggers a 500 error). I'm following the docs, but I can't seem to get it to work. When I test it with an invalid regex, it still gets passed to the form and I get a 500 error.

What am I doing wrong? (All the code for my form is below.)

```
class ConcordanceForm(forms.Form):
    error_css_class = 'error' #need to define this in stylesheet
    searchterm = forms.CharField(max_length=100, required=True)
    search_type = forms.ChoiceField(widget=RadioSelect(), 
                                    choices= ([('string', 'Exact'), ('lemma', 'Stem'), ('regex', 'Regex') ]),
                                    required=True )

    def clean_searchterm(self):
        cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
        searchterm = cleaned_data.get('searchterm')
        search_type = cleaned_data.get('search_type')
        if search_type == 'regex':
            try:
                re.search(searchterm, 'randomdatastring') #this is just to test if the regex is valid
            except re.error:
                raise forms.ValidationError("Invalid regular expression.")
        return searchterm


def concord_test(request):

    if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...
        form = ConcordanceForm(request.POST) # A form bound to the POST data
        if form.is_valid(): # All validation rules pass
            searchterm = form.cleaned_data['searchterm'].encode('utf-8')
            search_type = form.cleaned_data['search_type']
            context, texts_len, results_len = make_concordance(searchterm, search_type)
            return render_to_response('corpus/concord.html', locals()) # Redirect after POST
    else:
        form = ConcordanceForm() # An unbound form
    return render_to_response('corpus/search_test.html', 
                              {'form': form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))


<p style=" font-weight:bold;">Search for any word in the corpus:</p>
<form action="." method="post">{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be running into issues with using other values from `cleaned_data` in a `clean_{field}` function. switch it to a general `clean` function and you may have better luck. Also, its better form, because its a clean method that requires two fields' values in order for the validation to run.

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
    searchterm = cleaned_data.get('searchterm')
    search_type = cleaned_data.get('search_type')
    if search_type == 'regex':
        try:
            re.search(searchterm, 'randomdatastring') #this is just to test if the regex is valid
        except re.error:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Invalid regular expression.")
    return cleaned_data
```